# Java Tree traversal

Tags: java, recursion, tree-traversal, inorder

I am working on an API in which, I generate a query based on conditions tree received in request.
Following is the tree format:

[image: Tree]

It should get translated in the SQL query like this:

```
WHERE (a>b OR c<d) AND (e>f OR g<h)
```

Or, like this

```
WHERE ((a>b) OR (c<d)) AND ((e>f) OR (g<h))
```

Using pre-order traversal, I am able to generate the query. However, I am not able to append the brackets. Following is my inOrder traversal code:

```
public void inorder(Filter n, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (n != null) {
            inorder(n.getLeft(), builder);
            print(n, builder);
            inorder(n.getRight(), builder);
        }
    }

private void print(Filter node, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (null == node.getField() || null == node.getValue()) {
            builder.append(node.getLogicOperator());
        } else {
            builder.append((node.getField() + " " + node.getComparisonOperator() + " " + node
                    .getValue()));
        }
        builder.append("\n");
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me where to insert the brackets?
Thanks in advance.

****Update****

Now, I want to generate mongo query from the same structure. I am able to generate the string but unable to append the brackets: I want something like this:

```
$and : [
        { $or : [ { a: b}, { c: d } ] },
        { $or : [ { e: f}, { g: { $lt : h} } ] }
    ]
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you traverse the tree in order, the output will be:

```
inorder_traversal(n) = "(" + inorder_traversal(leftchild(n)) + n + 
                       inorder_traversal(rithtchild(n)) + ")"
```

It includes a bit of unnecessary brackets, but it shouldn't be a big deal.

For your example, it goes like:

```
( traversal(leftOR) AND traversal(rightOR) )
( ( traversal(a>b) OR traversal(c<d) ) AND ( traversal(e>f) OR traversal(g<h) )
( ( ( a>b ) OR ( c<d ) ) AND ( ( e> f) OR ( g<h ) ) )
```

Comment: Spot on! I did similar thing after thinking about scenarios. I also inserted the condition to not append brackets if the node is root node. Cheers!

Comment: Hello, Can you please provide some pointer for generating the string with brackets?